# Running C code using FastCGI & NGINX

Tags: c, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to run C code using FastCGI and NGINX. Right now, after following all the steps in this website: http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/

I am at the step where I am about to spawn-fcgi. However, the system that I must use is a 32 bit system where commands such as sudo apt-get install are not supported. I tried copying over the spawn-fcgi binary from my 64 bit system and tried using that like this: `./spawn-fcgi -p 8000 -n hello_world` command but it is giving me an error saying it cannot execute the binary file (I'm assuming it is because I am for sure on a 32 bit system when trying to use it). In fact, when I executed `file spawn-fcgi` it told me that it was a 64-bit LSB executable, and as I am running it on a 32-bit system, that's why the "Cannot execute binary file" error is there.

What I'm wondering is if there is anyway I could run a C script using FASTCGI without calling on `spawn-fcgi` or `cgi-fcgi` or if there is anyway I could use somehow get these binaries in 32-bit. I tried searching online for 32-bit downloads of FASTCGI but it seems like fastcgi.com is broken as I am unable to access the website.

Please let me know if I've left out any crucial information and I'll be glad to provide it. Thanks!

Comment: lets start with the appliciion to download is C++ not C.  Then what OS are you using.  The referenced web page on how to do the downloads is expecting a linux OS, not windows.  The question asks about C but the referenced web page is about C++

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong link. I was using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149709/c-language-fastcgi-with-nginx and was able to run C scripts on my Ubuntu mac, but now I'm developing in a different Linux environment that is just 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the API provided by `<fcgiapp.h>` header, you can specify the socket details, which *spawning* via external means does for you.

You can get a TCP socket file descriptor like this:

`int sockfd = FCGX_OpenSocket("127.0.0.1:9000", 100);`

...or using Unix sockets:

`int sockfd = FCGX_OpenSocket("/var/run/fcgi.sock", 100);`

With the socket you can then:

```
FCGX_Request req;
FCGX_InitRequest(&req, sockfd, 0);

while (FCGX_Accept_r(&req) >= 0) {
    FCGX_FPrintF(req.out, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
    FCGX_FPrintF(req.out, "hello world");
    FCGX_Finish_r(&req);
}
```

Once you compile, you can execute the binary directly without using `spawn-fcgi` or `cgi-fcgi`.